# I am trying to solve this question. But condition is dont touch listPrime function. Is it possible

Tags: c++

**Dont touch listPrime function just modify the main function.Also Must use listPrime to get return value ; Question from one of my senior classmate **

```
#include <iostream>
const int nmax = 100001;
bool isPrime[nmax];
int listPrime(int num){
 for(int i = 2; i<=num;i++){
  isPrime[i] = true;
 }
 for(int i = 2; i<=num/2;i++){
  if(isPrime[i]==true){
   for(int j =i*2;j<=num;j+=i){
    isPrime[j] = false;
   }  
  } 
 }
 for(int i=2;i<=num;i++){
  if(isPrime[i] == true){
   return i;
  }
 }
}

int main (){
 //Qn: Call the above function and get return all prime number lists from 1-100
 // but dont touch listPrime Function untill you think you can not do it
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: waht is the question? What is the intended outcome? Why do you want to modify anything in this code?

Comment: `listPrime` is fundamentally broken, it does not return on all code paths. If you cannot modify it then there is no way to fix this code

Comment: Read about the Sieve of Eratosthenes. Then you'll see what the function is doing, and understand how to pull the primes out of the `isPrime` array.

Comment: "but dont touch listPrime Function *untill you think you can not do it*" Not returning on all paths and the usage of global variables is the point where I think I cannot work with this code without touching the function ;)

Comment: This is the condition. Question is within main function using comment

Comment: The `i<=20` in the third loop looks broken as well.

Comment: That was 100 sorry..i was practicing with short value

Comment: `<= 100` seems wrong as well. Shouldn't it be `<= num`?  And shouldn't there be a check that `num < nmax`? This function is broken, I wouldn't try to work with it. But even then, what's your question? What did you try? What did fail? Please take our [tour] and see [ask] and show a [mre] of _your_ effort in solving this.

Comment: This function will still always (for sensible inputs) return 2. The `return` acts like a `break`, the loop will not continue afterwards. The only other thing that can happen is when you pass 1 for `num` which is the case where it wont return at all.

Comment: Check the ans below.  Maybe the return value in question said to make it hard.just dont modify the listPrime function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use the function's return value at all. I'm sure that final loop and return in the function is there to throw you off. It's completely pointless.

The function computes a prime sieve. If you just call it once, it'll generate the entire table for values up to whatever value you passed. So you may as well pass `nmax` to generate the entire table. Computing a sieve is very fast, especially for values as small as 100000.

Once the table is built, all you need to do is read the value at any valid index to know if that index is a prime number. It's unclear whether you want to show A) all primes up to 100; or B) the first 100 primes. I'll show both.

```
int main()
{
    listPrime(nmax);

    // Option A: Output primes up to 100
    for (int n = 0; n < 100; n++)
    {
        if (isPrime[n]) {
            std::cout << n << '\n';
        }
    }

    // Option B: Output first 100 primes
    for (int count = 0, n = 0; count < 100 && n < nmax; n++)
    {
        if (isPrime[n]) {
            count++;
            std::cout << "Prime " << count << " is " << n << '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man! It's real workeddddd.its like Think outside the box

Comment: Well, I guess, if the box is the function. So think outside the function (where lives the suspiciously global array containing everything you need).

Comment: Does c++ have array return way like i want to get all listPrime value in array then get the return in main function?

Comment: No, not an array. You could use `std::vector`. But that would constitute modifying the `listPrime` function, which you've already said is highly illegal.

Comment: Thanks man! That's actually i want to know if an array set can be return like int. I will try to solve this way

Comment: Well, you can return `std::array` by value, but it's generally not what you want. _e.g._ https://godbolt.org/z/MrajKPecj Anyway, you do what you want. You seem hell-bent on returning an array from a function. If that's what you wanna do, I'll stop trying to stop you. If you found the answer useful, consider voting and accepting it.